# How do I randomly select 1 row out of rows with partial match in 2 columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark 3.0.1. I have a student data frame `df`. The dataframe looks like

```
MathsMarks HistoryMarks id   class   TotalMarks
  80          75         1     9        300
  90          78         1     9        350
  65          70         7     8        250
  58          55         7     8        200
  75          72         7     8        260
  85          82         9     9        400
  82          85         15    8        410
```

I need to select randomly one record from the data if `id` & `class` combination is repeated more than one time.
For example, my outcome might look like

```
MathsMarks HistoryMarks id   class   TotalMarks
  80          75         1     9        300
  58          55         7     8        200
  85          82         9     9        400
  82          85         15    8        410
```

Can you suggest me how to do that?
After implementing @mck's step I'm getting duplicate while they are not in consecutive rows. For example

```
 Group MathsMarks HistoryMarks id   class   TotalMarks
   A      80          75         1     9        300
   A      90          78         1     null     350
   A      70          78         1     9        320
  
   B      65          70         7     8        250
   B      58          55         8     null     240
   B      65          70         7     8        250
   B      58          55         8     null     200
   C      85          82         9     9        400
   D      82          85         15    8        410
```

I want this in below way

```
 Group MathsMarks HistoryMarks id   class   TotalMarks
   A      80          75         1     9        300
   A      90          78         1     null     350
  
   B      65          70         7     8        250
   B      58          55         8     null     240
   C      85          82         9     9        400
   D      82          85         15    8        410
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "rn", 
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("id", "class").orderBy(F.lit(None)))
).filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")

df1.show()
#+----------+------------+---+-----+----------+
#|MathsMarks|HistoryMarks| id|class|TotalMarks|
#+----------+------------+---+-----+----------+
#|        65|          70|  7|    8|       250|
#|        82|          85| 15|    8|       410|
#|        85|          82|  9|    9|       400|
#|        80|          75|  1|    9|       300|
#+----------+------------+---+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `dropDuplicates` will do the job:

```
df.dropDuplicates(['id', 'class']).show()
+----------+------------+---+-----+----------+
|MathsMarks|HistoryMarks| id|class|TotalMarks|
+----------+------------+---+-----+----------+
|        82|          85| 15|    8|       410|
|        85|          82|  9|    9|       400|
|        80|          75|  1|    9|       300|
|        65|          70|  7|    8|       250|
+----------+------------+---+-----+----------+
```

Comment: It's not working when I don't have duplicate in consecutive rows say for example id & Class are in this format `id=1 class=8  id=1 class=9 id=1 class=8 id=1 class=9` can you suggest me how to resolve this?

Comment: @pysparkLearner could you show a sample dataframe please?

Comment: I tried `df.dropDuplicates(['id', 'class']).show()` and there were no duplicates. Could you show the code you used, and the output you got, please?

Comment: Sorry, I can't able to share with you my code & data. This is a dummy data set that I Prepared. Original data is client data.  I will double check the error & will share similar data set